# Jenkins get a filename of an artifact which has random suffix

Tags: jenkins

When I run a Webdriver test using Jenkins , my extend report is generated with date suffix.

Example-SingleExecutionReport_**11-08-2021 13-32-54**.html

In order to publish the report, I want to give like this in
Files to archive field.
MultiWebdriverDemo/ExtentReport/SingleExecutionReport_11-08-2021 13-32-54**.html

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the regex sign * for the section where that suffix need to be matched so it matches any characters.

MultiWebdriverDemo/ExtentReport/SingleExecutionReport_*.html
[image]

Then report should be available once the build it completed.
[image]